# SAP R/3 STMS error message "Does not match component version" / "Die installierte Komponenten-version stimmt nicht überein"

Tags: sap-basis

When trying to import a transport request via transaction `stms` into a SAP R/3 system there is an error message (german)

> Die installierte Komponenten-version stimmt nicht überein.

After logging out and logging in again with `EN` as language the english message is:

> Does not match component version.

How can I proceed?

Comment: I basically asked and answered this question so that users searching with the german error message on the public internet get at least a hint on what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bypass/ignore the error for a single import by ticking the checkbox "Ignore Invalid Component Version" in the transport request options.

Some official SAP notes (like [1671989](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1671989)) recommend to ignore the warning as described above, others (like [1688610](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1688610)) describe steps to prevent it from occuring in the first place. The latter note also describes a way to disable the warning entirely: In transaction `stms` chose "Systems Overview" → *ID of your system* → "Transport Tool" → "Change Mode" and set the parameter `SP_TRANS_SYNC` to `OFF`

A detailed explanation of what this error message is trying to tell you can be found in SAP note [1742547](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1742547).

[image: screenshot of transport request options]